# Instantiating static const and static constexpr member variables when they are not used

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, constexpr

In the following example I have a class template with a `static const` and a `static constexpr` member variable.

```
template <class T>
struct S {                                      // MSVC: clang:
    static const     bool value1 = T::value1;   // error error
    static constexpr bool value2 = T::value2;   // error OK
};

S<void> s;
```

In `S<void>` the member variables have a syntax error, but they are not used. MSVC and clang disagree whether to diagnose an error. See the comments in the code. [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6MGTWT93T).

Which compiler is right?

Comment: in your godbolt link both compilers issue an error, because `void` has no `value1`

Comment: oh ok, you are only refering to the second line. Why do you not remove the first then? Usually all errors but the first arent taken that serious because they can be just caused by the first. It is easy to overlook what you are talking about

Comment: clang just discard the `constexpr` member because it's not used in your code. If you had any reference to `value2` it would be an error for either compliers

Comment: You need to make use of `s.value2` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/d7GrGsE5r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you instantiate a specialization of a class template, it does not instantiate the definitions of the members of that class, only declarations. [[*]](https://wg21.link/temp.spec#temp.inst-3) For example:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct S {
    inline static int StaticDataMember = T{};
    struct NestedClass { T m; };
    int NonStaticDataMember = T{};
    template<typename U> using MemberTemplateTypedef = decltype(T{} + T{});
    int MemberFunction() { return T{}; }
    static int NonStaticMemberFunction() { return T{}; }
    friend int FriendNonMemberFunction() { return T{}; }
};

int x = sizeof(S<void>);  // Instantiates with T = void
```

Should compile, as only the declarations are instantiated when `S<void>` is.

That means that as long as you do not use the members, they should not be instantiated, so MSVC is being a little too eager.

However, it seems that clang is being eager to instantiate the definition of the `const bool` static data member. The reason seems to be that clang is checking that the initializer is a constant expression, because it is not marked `inline` and it is being initialized inline (which requires a constant expression). This check isn't done if you had had `inline static const bool value1 = T::value1;`.

Comment: I don't understand something. Both `value1` and `value2` must be initialized with a constant expression. I have [played](https://godbolt.org/z/ME1nseM8s) with it a little. Yet it leads to the compiler having to check only `T::value1`. Why not `T::value2`? Would you please include this into hte answer?

Comment: In this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/556sxjnhq) both compilers are eager.

Comment: @Dr.Gut In your example, `using type = T::type;` is the same as `typedef T::type type;`. This declaration (not the definition) is instantiated when the class is, leading to the error. I agree that `value2` must also be initialized by a constant expression, so I've changed my answer. I've gotten my answer from here: <https://wg21.link/temp.spec#temp.inst-3> which shows a member function, but a static data member and it's definition should be no different.

Comment: I think you actually found the relevant references. In C++20 [\[temp.inst\]#3.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.inst#3.1) says *the declarations, but not the definitions of static data members are instantiated*. And #4 confirms it (see the end of the sentence: *in particular...*). So both compilers have to accept both `value1` and `value2`, since they are not used. It turns out that checking whether the initializer is a constant expression, has also to be deferred until the first use of the static data member.